# some operator questions

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala so sorry if this is easy but I've had a hard time finding the answer.

I'm having a hard time understanding what <- does, and what ()=> Unit does. My understanding of these is that -> is sometimes used in foreach, and that => is used in maps. Trying to google "scala "<-" doesn't prove very fruitful. I found http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2008/12/scala-operator-cheat-sheet.html but it wasn't as helpful as it looks at first glance.

```
val numbers = List("one", "two", "three","four","five")
def operateOnList() {
  for(number <- numbers) {
    println(number + ": came out of this crazy thing!")
  }
}

def tweener(method: () => Unit) {
  method()
}

tweener(operateOnList)
```

Comment: Did you look at http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-symbols.html?

Answer (score 5):

`() => Unit` means that method is a function that takes no parameter and returns nothing (`Unit`).

`<-` is used in the for comprehension as an kind of assignation operator. for comprehension are a little bit specific because they are internally transformed. In your case, that would be transforms as `numbers.foreach(i => println(i + ": came out of this crazy thing!"))`

`<-` in the for comprehension means that we will iterate over each element of the `numbers` list and passed to `number`.

Comment: Thanks that does help a lot. I get now that we define what tweener accepts as a function called method, but why do we need to specify that it returns nothing? I do get errors about parenthesis if I just put def tweener(method: ()), but I don't understand why. Also I get <- now, thanks!

Comment: because `Unit` means nothing :-) It's a kind of typed `void` that you know in C or Java languages.

Comment: @user1054583 I take issue with the "nothing". Nothing in Scala returns nothing: everything returns something, unless it doesn't return, but throws an exception instead (like `sys.error`, whose return type is `Nothing`). Now, sometimes you are not interested in what is being returned, and that's and `Unit` really means: it's a type with a single value -- `()` -- that you simply ignore.

Answer (score 4):

'<-' could be threated as 'in' so

```
for(number <- numbers){
...
}
```

could be translated into english as *for each number in numbers do*

'<-' has a twin with a different semantics: '->'. Simply it is just a replacement of comma in tuples: (a,b) is an equivalent to (a->b) or just a->b. The meaning after this symbols is that 'a' *maps* to 'b'. So this is often used in definition of Maps:

```
 Map("a" -> 1,"aba" -> 3)
 Map("London" -> "Britain", "Paris" -> "France")
```

Here you can think about mapping as a projection (or not) via some function (e.g. 'length of string', 'capital of').

**Better explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980515/scala-maps-operator/4980692#4980692).**

Last, but not least is '=>' which is map too, but with a general semantics. '=>' is in use all over the place in anonymous expressions:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4).map(current => current+1)
res5: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Which is *for each element map current element of list with function 'plus one'*

```
List(1,2,3,4).map(c => c%2 match {
     | case 0 => "even"
     | case 1 => "odd"
     | }
     | )
res6: List[java.lang.String] = List(odd, even, odd, even)
```

*Map current element with provided pattern mathing*

Comment: Thank you for your <- explanation, that really helps clear it up! For def tweener(method: ()=> Unit) I'm having a hard time understanding what this does other than accepting the method (I get that bit!). Thanks for your explanation, but I guess I'll have to chock my continued lack of understanding on just plain poor scala foo

Answer (score 3):

In the method

```
def tweener(method: () => Unit) {
  method()
}
```

the method is called `tweener`, the parameter is arbitrarily named `method`, and the type of `method` is `() => Unit`, which is a function type, as you can tell from the `=>`.

`Unit` is a return type similar to `void` in Java, and represents no interesting value being returned. For instance, the return type of `print` is `Unit`. `()` represents an empty parameter list.

Confusingly, `()` is also used to represent an instance of `Unit`, called the *unit value*, the only value a `Unit` can take. But this is *not* what it means in the function type `() => Unit`, just as you can't have a function type `42 => Unit`.

Back to your example, `tweener` takes a *function* of type `() => Unit`. `operateOnList` is a *method*, but it gets partially applied by the compiler to turn it into a function value. You can turn methods into functions yourself like this:

```
scala> def m = println("hi")
m: Unit

scala> m _
res17: () => Unit = <function0>
```

`operateOnList` can be turned into the right type of function because its parameter list is empty `()`, and its return type is implicity `Unit`.

As a side-note, if `operateOnList` were defined without the empty parameter list (as is legal, but more common when the return type is not Unit), you would need to manually partially apply it, else its value will be passed instead:

```
def f1() {}
def f2 {}
def g(f: () => Unit) {}
g(f1)   // OK
g(f2)   // error, since we're passing f2's result (), 
        //   rather than partial function () => Unit
g(f2 _) // OK
```