# Why is a return statement required to allow this while statement to be evaluated properly?

Tags: scala

Why is a return statement required to allow this while statement to be
evaluated properly?  The following statement allows

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader

trait Closeable {
  def close ()
}

trait ManagedCloseable extends Closeable {
  def use (code: () => Unit) {
    try {
      code()
    }
    finally {
      this.close()
    }
  }
}

class CloseableInputStream (stream: InputStream)
extends InputStream with ManagedCloseable {
  def read = stream.read
}

object autoclose extends App {
  implicit def inputStreamToClosable (stream: InputStream):
    CloseableInputStream = new CloseableInputStream(stream)

  override
  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    val test = new FileInputStream(new File("test.txt"))

    test use {
      val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(test))

      var input: String = reader.readLine

      while (input != null) {
        println(input)
        input = reader.readLine
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This produces the following error from scalac:

```
autoclose.scala:40: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: () => Unit
      while (input != null) {
      ^
one error found
```

It appears that it's attempting to treat the block following the `use` as an
inline statement rather than a lambda, but I'm not exactly sure why.  Adding
`return` after the while alleviates the error:

```
test use {
  val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(test))

  var input: String = reader.readLine

  while (input != null) {
    println(input)
    input = reader.readLine
  }

  return
}
```

And the application runs as expected.  Can anyone describe to me what is going
on there exactly?  This seems as though it should be a bug.  It's been
persistent across many versions of Scala though (tested 2.8.0, 2.9.0, 2.9.1)

Comment: I'm not familiar with `scala`, but is `reader.readLine` supposed to be `reader.readLine()` with the parenthesis?

Comment: @Jon, no, in Scala, you can call a 0-argument function without parenthesis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because it's `use` is declared as `() => Unit`, so the compiler expects the block you are giving `use` to return something that satisfies this signature.

It seems that what you want is to turn the entire block into a by-name parameter, to do so change `def use (code : () => Unit)` to `def use (code : => Unit)`.

Answer (score 3):

`() => Unit` is the type of a `Function0` object, and you've required the `use` expression to be of that type, which it obviously isn't. `=> Unit` is a *by name* parameter, which you should use instead.

You might find my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8205551/770361) useful.

Answer (score 3):

To go the heart of the matter, **blocks are not lambdas**. A block in Scala is a *scope delimiter*, nothing more.

If you had written

```
test use { () =>
  val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(test))

  var input: String = reader.readLine

  while (input != null) {
    println(input)
    input = reader.readLine
  }
}
```

Then you'd have a function (indicated by `() =>`) which is *delimited* by the block.

If `use` had been declared as

```
def use (code: => Unit) {
```

Then the syntax you used would work, but *not* because of any lambda thingy. That syntax indicates the parameter is passed *by name*, which, roughly speaking, means you'd take the whole expression passed as parameter (ie, the whole block), and substitute it for `code` inside the body of `use`. The *type* of `code` would be `Unit`, not a function, but the parameter would not be passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

`return` or `return expr` has the type `Nothing`. You can substitute this for *any* type, as it never yields a value to the surrounding expression, instead it returns control to the caller.

In your program, it masquerades as the required type `() => Unit`.

Here's an occasionally convenient use for that (although you might be tarnished as unidiomatic if you use it too often, don't tell anyone you heard this from me!)

```
def foo(a: Option[Int]): Int = {
  val aa: Int = a.getOrElse(return 0)
  aa * 2
}
```

For the record, you should probably write:

```
def foo(a: Option[Int]): Int =
  a.map(_ * 2).getOrElse(0)
```

You can get an insight into the mind of the compiler by checking the output of `scala -Xprint:typer -e <one-liner>`. Add `-Ytyper-debug` if you like sifting through the reams of output!

```
scala210 -Ytyper-debug -Xprint:typer -e 'def foo: Any = {val x: () => Any = { return }}'
... elided ...
   typed return (): Nothing
    adapted return (): Nothing to () => Any,
```

Comment: This explains why you must include a return type on your method when you use `return xyz` rather than just `xyz` at the end... was wondering about that