# How to use 'tuple' keywords in scala?

Tags: scala, authentication, playframework-2.0, tuples, reserved-words

I am studying scala.
For an practice, I am building a login page.
To do this, I have been searched examples on web.

I found some interesting code like below.

```
  val loginForm = Form(
    tuple(
        "username"->nonEmptyText, 
        "password"->nonEmptyText
    )
  )
```

I think after '->', it has to be an reserved words, right?
I wonder how many reserved word can be in this place.

Especially some type like password.
Any reference or example will be greatly welcomed :D

Comment: It's informative to read over `Predef.scala` - https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/Predef.scala - where the `->` method and a lot of other interesting stuff is defined.

Comment: There is no "tuple" keyword in Scala. There are only the `TupleN` defined names, where *N* is, prior to Scala 2.11, a small (-ish) integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->` is actually just an operator to make creating a Tuple2 (or Pair) object easier. See [the hairy details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4980734/2864740), for "how" such an operator can work across different types.

The normal/predef meaning of the `->` operator is such that `x -> y` is equivalent to `Tuple2(x, y)`, where `y` is just an expression. The code can then use *any* expression (reserved words or not) that is *valid* in the context.

In Play, note that `nonEmptyText` is itself just a value and does not involve any reserved words. Likewise, `tuple` is just a method for Play; see [Handling form submission](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaForms).

Comment: Thanks. I thought 'tuple' is spring keyword. but now I clearly understand :-)